# C# Read Byte [] to Image

Tags: c#, image, byte, converters

I have an application which I'm adding pictures and these are automatically converted to binary and stored in a single file. how can I save several images, I keep in an XML file start and size of each set of refente to an image byte. But it has several images in bytes, whenever I try to select a different set of bytes just opening the same image. I would like your help to be able to fix this and open different images.

Code

//Add Image

```
private void btAddImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
            op.Title = "Selecione a Imagem";
            op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
                "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
                "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";

            if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                imgPatch.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
                txtName.Focus();
            }
        }


//Convert Image

 private void btConvertImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text))
            {
                txtName.Focus();
                MessageBox.Show("Preencha o Nome", "Error");
            }

            else
            {
                save(ConvertFileToByteArray(op.FileName), txtName.Text);
            }
        }

//Image to Byte Array

private static byte[] ConvertFileToByteArray(String FilePath)
        {
            return File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
        }


//Save Binary File and XML File

public void save(byte[] img, string nome)
        {
            FileStream f;
            long ini, fin = img.Length; 

            if (!File.Exists("Escudos.bcf"))
            {
                f = new FileStream("Escudos.bcf", FileMode.Create);
                ini = 0;
            }

            else
            {
                f = new FileStream("Escudos.bcf", FileMode.Append);
                ini = f.Length + 1;
                bin = new TestBinarySegment();

            }

            bin.LoadAddSave("Escudos.xml", "Brasileiro", nome, ini, fin);



            BinaryWriter b = new BinaryWriter(f);
            b.Write(img);
            b.Close();
            f.Dispose();



        }


//Load Image from Byte
private void btLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            getImageFromByte();
        }


//Byte to Image
public void getImageFromByte(int start, int length)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Escudos.bcf", FileMode.Open))
            {
                byte[] iba = new byte[fs.Length+1];
                fs.Read(iba, start, length);
                Image image = new Image();
                image.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(fs, BitmapCreateOptions.None,
                                          BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);

                imgPatch2.Source = image.Source;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does that even compile? You call `getImageFromByte()` but pass no parameters.

Comment: I forgot to put in there, but the application has

Comment: Then *edit* your question. It's really hard for people to give good answers when your question is full of misleading stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *offset* parameter to [FileStream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the starting offset in the buffer where you want the data to be placed. If you want to read from an offset in the stream, you have to `Seek` to that position. I think what you want is below, although I'm not entirely certain what `BitmapFrame.Create` will do if there's more data in the file beyond the image it's trying to read.

```
fs.Seek(start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(fs, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
```

That moves the file pointer to the correct starting position.

I eliminated the byte array because you don't appear to be using it for anything constructive.

If that doesn't work, then you'll have to read the data into a byte array, create a `MemoryStream`, and create the bitmap from that:

```
byte[] ida = new byte[length];
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("Escudos.bcf"))
{
    fs.Seek(start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    fs.Read(ida, 0, length);
}
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ida))
{
    Image image = new Image();
    image.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(fs, BitmapCreateOptions.None,
        BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
    imgPatch2.Source = image.Source;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is apparently correct, but I tried to call the code in two different ways: getImageFromByte (0,12161); and getImageFromByte (12162,19905); In theory, was to open two different images, but opens the same image

Comment: @LucasGuitar: Did you try both examples? Did you single-step the code and investigate what it's doing? Also, are you certain that your saving code is writing the file correctly?

Comment: I think the error is time to create the binary file

Comment: I got! I'll put the full code in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is the use serialization and deserialization

Make a class

```
[serializable]
myImage
{
   Byte[] ImageData;
}

Add each image to a List
List<myImage>
```

write direct to file using serialization 
Read direct to List using deserialization

Comment: I could not understand